# Can find server on the network, but not able to connect via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, router

Server machine is running: Ubuntu Server 18.04.02

I've checked and server is running the SSH service. Follow some details:

```
netstat -natp | grep ssh

tcp     0       0.0.0.0:22  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  2873/sshd
tcp6    0   0   :::22       :::*        LISTEN  2873/sshd
```

Firewall disable with command:

```
ufw disable

Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

ufw status

Status: inactive
```

On the client side i try to connect the server:

```
ssh user@10.10.35.7

ssh: connect to host 10.10.35.7 port 22: Operation timed out
```

I'm not sure if is my server or there's configuration on the router that is blocking me from connecting to other devices, but i'm using a tool for IP scanning and i'm able to see all my 3 computers connected  to the router using  the same account (username and password).
I don't have access to the routers, as they distributed throughout the building, and seems like there's no admin interface :s :s

Does anyone have any clue what's going on and how can i solve it?

Comment: Is `firewalld` running? If so, add the output of `firewall-cmd --list-ports` and `firewall-cmd --list-services` to your question.

Comment: I don't have ```firewalld``` installed. Just the default firewall (ufw) that is disabled

Comment: If `firewalld` and `iptables` aren't running and you have `ufw` disabled, then the only thing left is that there is something in a router/switch/external firewall that's blocking the port or connections in general between the client and the server. Are they on the same subnet? Can you `ssh` from another computer?

Comment: What's the output of: `telnet 10.10.35.7 22`? What's the output of: `ssh user@10.10.35.7`? From the description, it sounds like a rule is in place that isn't allowing SSH connections over wireless, at the very least. Can you connect two devices to the wired network and then SSH from one to the other?

Comment: Can you ping the server from the client? How about the other way? Of course, ICMP may have been disabled, but if not, pinging is the first step. *If* that works, then you can try telnet, ssh, etc. If pinging does not work, check routes. If those look good, then check physical connections. Then talk to IT, since you can't touch the routers.

Comment: `ssh -v` should be checked.